# support working storyboard for iphone 5/5s to iphone 4/4s ?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Since I am new to iphone developing so need to clear my basics regarding the UI support for all the iphones. Right now I have made an app for iphone 5/5s which seems to be working nicely, now I want to support the same for iphone 4/4s using the same storyboard

When I try to run my application on iphone 4/4s everything seems to be scaled up.. There is Ads UIView added programatically at the bottom which is out of the screen

So now I need a basic Idea of which resolution Image I should use and is it going to be @2x?

Comment: Take a look at auto layout and constraints. You don't need to add @2x images. They're for retina displays which you're currently working on.

Comment: image resolution is not an issue over there. Issue is with the height of screen for iphone5/5S its 568 and others 480 so you need to change the frames as per your requirement. if other than Ads every thing is looking good means just change Ads frame in your code. if not create a new story board for other than iPhone5/5S or manage frames with code

Comment: @BoranA : I am not sure but I find this constraint thing very difficult to understand ... What I did is made the separate storyboard for the iphone 4/4s

Comment: @user1201239 : It's a good method too and easy to implement. The only disadvantage is; if you want to change something on ui you need to do same thing twice.